# How to send array of data in post request in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter code I need to send array of objects on a http post request, but it can not be encoded as json object.

here is my flutter class to send data to the service

```
class JobCreateRequestModel {
  String? category;
  String? title;
  String? description;
  String? latitude;
  String? longitude;
  List<Job.Images>? images;

  JobCreateRequestModel(
    {this.category,
    this.title,
    this.description,
    this.latitude,
    this.longitude,
    this.images});

    Map<String?, dynamic> toJson() {
     Map<String?, dynamic> map = {
      category: category,
      title: title,
      description: description,
      latitude: latitude,
      longitude: longitude,
      images: images
     };

     return map;
   }
}

class Images {
   String? id;
   String? name;
   String? type;
   String? url;
   double? size;
   String? uploadedAt;

  Images(Images item,
      {this.id, this.name, this.type, this.url, this.size, this.uploadedAt});
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['type'] = this.type;
    data['url'] = this.url;
    data['size'] = this.size;
    data['uploadedAt'] = this.uploadedAt;
   return data;
  }
}
```

This class should be created this kind of object

```
{
    "category": "1604173705548",
    "title": "title",
    "description": "For See More, We need to calculate how much text can be inserted in a given number of lines or Space.",
    "latitude": "23.00343",
    "longitude": "23.00343",
    "images": [
        {
            "id": "16114286013370",
            "name": "200820_4.jpeg",
            "type": ".jpeg",
            "url": "https://sample.com/job_images/16114286013370.jpeg",
            "size": "72.369",
            "uploadedAt": "1611428601337"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have used form to get the required data to the model and need to convert it in to json encodable object. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your JSON format to generate the model class :

```
import 'dart:convert';

JobCreateRequestModel jobCreateRequestModelFromJson(String str) => JobCreateRequestModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String jobCreateRequestModelToJson(JobCreateRequestModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class JobCreateRequestModel {
    JobCreateRequestModel({
        this.category,
        this.title,
        this.description,
        this.latitude,
        this.longitude,
        this.images,
    });

    String category;
    String title;
    String description;
    String latitude;
    String longitude;
    List<Image> images;

    factory JobCreateRequestModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => JobCreateRequestModel(
        category: json["category"],
        title: json["title"],
        description: json["description"],
        latitude: json["latitude"],
        longitude: json["longitude"],
        images: List<Image>.from(json["images"].map((x) => Image.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "category": category,
        "title": title,
        "description": description,
        "latitude": latitude,
        "longitude": longitude,
        "images": List<dynamic>.from(images.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Image {
    Image({
        this.id,
        this.name,
        this.type,
        this.url,
        this.size,
        this.uploadedAt,
    });

    String id;
    String name;
    String type;
    String url;
    String size;
    String uploadedAt;

    factory Image.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Image(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        type: json["type"],
        url: json["url"],
        size: json["size"],
        uploadedAt: json["uploadedAt"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "type": type,
        "url": url,
        "size": size,
        "uploadedAt": uploadedAt,
    };
}
```

What you can do is simply while posting data to server use :

```
jobCreateRequestModelToJson(yourClassObject)
```

This should work! Hope this is what you wanted

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it worked as expected. Thank you again